# Get a row in applescript by AXStaticText

Tags: applescript

```
value of static text of row 1 of (table 1 of some scroll area)
        --> {"Wi-Fi, Connected"}

select (row of (table 1 of some scroll area)
            whose (value of static text) begins with "Wi-Fi")
error "Can’t get attribute \"AXValue\" of static text."
            number -1728 from «class attr» "AXValue" of «class sttx»
```

While I can get the value, why I can't use it as a filter in 'whose' clause?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`value of static text` seems to return a list like `{"Wi-Fi, Connected"}`. Try using a repeat loop that coerces the list to text:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    repeat with r in rows of table 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1
        if (value of static text of r as text) starts with "Wi-Fi" then return r
    end repeat
end tell
```